# How do you refer to a signatory before they've signed a document?

Tags: legalese, correspondence

Pretty much the title. I have a contract with some people who have to sign it to make it official. By what descriptive noun do I refer to these people? "Presumptive signatory"?

Comment: Rube, patsy, sucker, fish-on-the-hook...

Answer (score 2):

They are parties to a contract and, depending on the type of contract, they are called *lessor/lessee, buyer/seller, grantor/grantee*, etc.

They are the **potential signatories** (in fact, before signing the document, they are not even parties to the contract, because it has not yet been executed and is therefore not effective).